# How to prevent the form Submission in JSF until a panel has completed the rendering?

Tags: jsf-2

In my application I have a SelecOneMenu which shows some items like below..

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="cmbInput" value="#{myBean.val}" required="true" requiredMessage="Some Message">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Please select" noSelectionOption="true" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.items}" />
            <f:ajax event="valueChange" render="myPanel"/>
            <f:ajax listener="#{myBean.myListener}"/>            
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Basically whenever user select an item it will render a panel below which have some input fields like below..

```
<h:panelGroup id="myPanel" rendered="#{myBean.someFlag}">
   <h:inputText id="input1" value="#{myBean.someVal}" required="true">
</h:panelGroup>
```

And there is a "Next" button which takes the user to the next page.

The problem I am facing is that whenever user is seleting something from the dropdown and clicking on the next button before the panel is rendered it is taking him to the next page. But I want to prevent it as that panel contain fields which needs to be entered so I want to throw validation errors on clicking next in this case.

Comment: If you can use primefaces in your project take a look at ajax status component [Ajax Status](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/pprAjaxStatusScript.jsf)

Answer (score 0):

[JQuery Validate plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) would be the best choice in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Few things you can do is

1. Show Loading... image so that user knows something is happening.
2. You can make use of jQuery Block Ui Plugin along with Loading... image.
3. Javascript validation I doubt will work as html elements will not be present immediately after selection is made until view is updated, and during this window user can click next, you can check for presence of html elements and your js validation or you can have server side validation.

Hope this helps.....